# Searching 3 joined tables in sql

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Am currently having an issue with my sql query in WordPress. So the issue am having is for some reason or another I cannot seem to search in a joined table without getting table does not exist errors.

My query is as follows:

```
$userOrders = $wpdb->prefix.'user_orders';
$users = $wpdb->prefix.'users';
$userAddedInfo = $wpdb->prefix.'user_added_info';
$userData = $postData;
$query = "select u.*, ue.*, pmo.*
  from $users u
  LEFT JOIN
  $userAddedInfo ue on ue.userId = u.id
  right JOIN
  $userOrders pmo on pmo.userId = u.id";
$whereClausePrefix = ' where';
```

My if statement based on conditions is as follows:

```
  if (!empty($userData->locationSearchText)) {
     $conditions = $whereClausePrefix." $userAddedInfo.city = '".$userData->locationSearchText."'";
 if ($whereClausePrefix === ' where') {
    $whereClausePrefix === ' and';
  }
}
```

Lastly my execution statement is as follows:

```
if (!empty($conditions)) {
 $results =  $query .$conditions;
}
if (empty($conditions)) {
 $results =  $query;
}
$results = $wpdb->get_results($results);
return $results;
```

My error message is as follows:

```
<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> [Column &#039;city&#039; in where clause is ambiguous]<br /><code>select u.*, ue.*, pmo.*
  from wp_dmp_lucystevens_users u
  LEFT JOIN
  wp_dmp_lucystevens_user_added_info ue on ue.userId = u.id
  right JOIN
  wp_dmp_lucystevens_user_orders pmo on pmo.userId = u.id where city = &#039;Cape Town&#039;</code></p></div>{"data":[]}
```

Comment: In your conditions code clause, what does `$user_extended.city` refer to?

Comment: Does the error mention which table doesn't exist?

Comment: @Junaid Sorry, I forgot to change that when posting the message. That field is $userAddedInfo.city.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have added the error message above.

Comment: The error message doesn't say a table doesn't exist, it says it doesn't know which `city` column you refer to. Apparently it occurs in at least two tables, and it doesn't know which one you mean.

Comment: I have tried to specify it as $userAddedInfo.city but still no luck.

Comment: That's because you've given the table an alias, so you have to refer to the table by it's alias, not its actual name

Comment: @BrianTananganjiManda, you need to specify which city column you want select. e.g tableName.columnName

Comment: @Sudhakar, thanks for the suggestion. That worked out perfectly.